# (Hypothetical) Write off Loss of Cash due to bankruptcy of financial institution

Tags: united-states, taxes, canada, bankruptcy, capital-loss

In both Canada and the United States, how do we write off the loss due to bankruptcy of the financial institution **in excess of** deposit insurance on the tax return for the tax year when the bankruptcy occurred?

Is it a capital loss? Or is it some other kind of loss?

Comment: "*Some internet users suggest*" lots of stupid things they pull out of their arses.  Why should we trust them?

Comment: I wouldn't put all of my eggs in one basket but Massachusetts banks are insured by the Depositors Insurance Fund and there's no $250k limit.  It's available to non residents.  I don't know if there are any hidden risks. It's an assumption that banks will fail on a scale worse than 2008 if the market craters more than it did in 2008.  The cause of that bear market was financial (subprime lending, CDOs, etc.).  If the cause isn't financial (like the -50% Internet Bubble), banks will be fine.

Comment: Much of the question tries to motivate *why* someone might hold large amounts of cash, but this isn't essential to the question. Just the last paragraph is enough.

Comment: FDIC [has been covering](https://www.americanbanker.com/opinion/will-fdic-keep-protecting-failed-banks-uninsured-deposits) *all* deposits at failed banks lately.

Comment: To the close voter: This is a question about income tax for an individual and is on-topic.

Comment: @nanoman that may not happen during a widespread financial downturn.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a frame challenge. It seems @BobBaerker's comment of *I wouldn't put all of my eggs in one basket* would lead to not having *any* losses above FDIC/NCUA insurance, and thus avoid the question. Just park your money in different accounts at different institutions.

Comment: @dwizum "_Don't be in that situation_" is obviously good advice, but I think this is a useful question to have an answer to for anyone that _is_ in "that situation" for whatever reason.